# Status of Euhemerus theory on Zeus

Tags: greek, zeus

Euhemerus (4th Century BC) is famous for his attempt to interpret myths as deformed historical events. In particular he thought that Zeus was originally a Cretan king whose tomb could be found in Crete. This theory was followed by a few of his contemporaries and later by Christian scholars, including early chistians such as Cyprian in *De idolorum vanitate* (3rd Century AD) and to some extent even 17th century historians such as Antoine Banier in *La Mythologie et les fables expliquées par l'histoire* (1711; litteraly *Mythology and fable explained by history*).

Without going into the details of the actual tomb which seems a little bit far-fetched, does any modern scholar (mythologist?) give any credit to the idea that Zeus was a king, later deified by the rumor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.** Modern scholarship usually considers [Zeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus) to be the Greek continuation of a [Proto-Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_religion) sky deity reconstructed as [***Dyēus ph<sub>2</sub>ter**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyeus). In fact, of all the Greek pantheon, Zeus is the most obviously descended from a prehistorical deity common to the [Proto-Indo-European peoples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Europeans). Under the prevailing consensus, therefore, Zeus is not a deified [Cretan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crete) king.

> The same root for 'shine' furnished the name of the head of the PIE pantheon, a god called Father Sky, whose name is securely reconstructible from the exact equation of Vedic Sanskrit *dyàuṣ pítar* '(o) Father Sky', Greek *Zeu pater* '(o) Father Zeus', and the Latin *Iū-piter* 'Jupiter' (Literlaly 'father Jove', also originally a vocative or form of direct address like the previous two."
>
> **<sub>- Fortson, B. *[Indo-European Language and Culture: an Introduction.](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1405188960.html)* Oxford: Blackwell Publishing, 2004.</sub>**

More generally, [Euhemerus'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euhemerus) theory on the origin of myths has one essential flaw. There is typically no evidence to support historical explanations for mythical events or figures. In the case of Zeus, the evidence that he dates back to the time of Proto-Indo-Europeans makes the theory that he was a (relatively) more recent Cretan king quite unlikely.

> Euhemerus' theory has one basic weakness. In most cases, modern scholars lack enough historical evidence to determine whether a mythical figure ever existed.
>
> **<sub>- Jacobs, Dale W. The World Book Encyclopedia. World Book Inc, 1997.</sub>**